# How can I prevent an option that requires an argument to use the next option when no argument is given?

Tags: shell, sh, getopts

I have the following code in test.sh:

```
while getopts "f:i:" opt; do
  case $opt in
  f)
    echo $OPTARG
  i) echo $OPTARG
```

Now if I run `./test.sh -f` I will get the error:

```
option requires an argument -- i
```

However, when I run `./test.sh -f -i test` it will echo -i.

I know that this is because it just gets the next argument separated by a space, but is there an easy way to handle this?

I could do `if [ $OPTARG == "-i" ]; then exit 1` but I'm hoping there is an easier way for when I have multiple options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using getopts, it has it's own ways. Just go with it.

After all, who says the option's argument cannot begin with a dash? If it's a filename, maybe the user wants the filename to begin with a dash. If it's a number, maybe it is a negative number.